# How to move schema objects to a different tablespace

Tags: sql, oracle, tablespace

I am using Oracle database 12c. 
I understand that a tablespace is a logical storage unit made up of one or more datafiles in which data about schema objects is stored. I also understand how to create tablespaces.

My question is: Which schema objects can be assigned to different tablespaces? How can we assign these objects to a tablespace using SQL?

EDIT:

I have found that to move a table to a different tablespace, we use the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE NAME to be moved> MOVE TABLESPACE <destination TABLESPACE NAME>
```

Additionally, to move a corresponding index to a tablespace, we use the following syntax after executing the above query:

```
alter index <owner>."<index_name>" rebuild;
```

However, are there any more schema objects that can be moved to a tablespace like the above?

Comment: For the index you forgot to include the tablespace to rebuild the index in; use `alter index <owner>."<index_name>" rebuild tablespace foo;`

Comment: The [documentation page for `DBA_SEGMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DBA_SEGMENTS.html) includes a list of segment types. If you are moving partitions, you might also want to check `DBA_PART_TABLES.DEF_TABLESPACE_NAME` and ensure the default tablespace for new partitions is the new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an Oracle package [DBMS_REDEFINITION.REDEF_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS74410) that can in theory move a table and its associated objects (indexes and LOBs). It handles partitioned tables too.

If that does not work, or if you want a better understanding of what pieces can go where, there are the following objects to consider:

- Tables and indexes
- Partitioned tables and indexes; as William Robertson mentioned, you need to ensure that for partitioned objects, you also need to alter the DEF_TABLESPACE value in addition to moving existing data/indexes.
- `LOB` (Large Object) columns of tables, such as `CLOB` and `BLOB` data types
- Index-organized tables which is really an index instead of a real table.

The following SQL generates SQL to move the existing objects; you will want to change the criteria as needed for your situation; this shows moving objects owned by `SCOTT` from `SYSAUX` tablespace to `TARGET_TS`:

## Tables

```
select 'alter table ' || do.owner || '.' || do.object_name ||
       ' move tablespace TARGET_TS;' as cmd_to_invoke 
from dba_objects do, dba_segments ds, dba_tables dt
where do.owner = 'SCOTT'
  and do.owner=ds.owner and do.owner=dt.owner
  and do.object_name = ds.segment_name and do.object_name=dt.table_name
  and dt.iot_name is null and do.object_type='TABLE'
  and ds.tablespace_name = 'SYSAUX';
```

### Partitioned Tables

```
alter table SCOTT.EMP modify default attributes tablespace TARGET_TS;
```

-- Then invoke the SQL generated by this query:

```
select distinct 'alter table ' || dt.table_owner || '.' || dt.table_name ||
        ' move partition ' || dt.partition_name ||
                             ' tablespace TARGET_TS' || ';' as cmd_to_invoke 
from
     dba_tab_partitions dt
where dt.table_owner='SCOTT'and dt.tablespace_name='SYSAUX'
order by 1;
```

### IOT Tables

```
select 'alter table ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ' move tablespace DEF_TABLESPACE;'
from dba_indexes
where owner = 'SCOTT'
and index_type = 'IOT - TOP'
and tablespace_name='SYSAUX';
```

## Indexes

```
select 'alter index ' || do.owner || '.' || do.object_name || ' rebuild tablespace apex;' as cmd
from dba_objects do, dba_segments ds, dba_indexes di
where do.owner = 'SCOTT'
  and do.owner=ds.owner and do.owner=di.owner
  and do.object_type = 'INDEX'
  and di.index_type in('NORMAL', 'FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL')
  and do.object_name = ds.segment_name and do.object_name = di.index_name 
  and ds.tablespace_name='SYSAUX';
```

### Partitioned Indexes

Similar to Partitioned Tables but using `alter index` and referencing either `DBA_INDEXES` or `DBA_IND_PARTITIONS`

## LOBS

### LOBS on Non-partitioned Tables

```
select distinct 'alter table ' || dtc.owner || '.' || dtc.table_name || 
   ' move lob(' || column_name || ')' ||
   ' store as (tablespace DEF_TABLESPACE);' as cmd_to_invoke
from dba_tab_columns dtc,
     dba_tables dt,
     dba_indexes di
where dt.owner=dtc.owner and dt.owner=di.owner
  and dt.table_name=di.table_name and dt.table_name=dtc.table_name
  and dtc.owner = 'SCOTT' and  dtc.data_type like '%LOB%'
  and di.index_name in 
     (select segment_name from dba_segments inner 
      where inner.owner=dt.owner and tablespace_name='SYSAUX') 
  ;
```

### LOBS on Partitioned Tables

```
select distinct 'alter table ' || dtc.owner || '.' || dtc.table_name ||
        ' move partition ' || dt.partition_name ||
        ' lob(' || column_name || ')' || ' store as (tablespace TARGET_TS)' ||
        ';'
from dba_tab_columns dtc,
     dba_tab_partitions dt,
     dba_indexes di
where dt.table_owner=dtc.owner and dt.table_owner=di.owner
  and dt.table_name=di.table_name and dt.table_name=dtc.table_name
and dtc.owner ='SCOTT' and dtc.data_type like '%LOB%'
and di.index_name in 
   (select segment_name from dba_segments inner 
    where inner.owner=dt.table_owner and tablespace_name='SYSAUX')
```